# Don't understand the using of IDisposable

Tags: c#, log4net, idisposable

Would someone explain the following C# code a little bit for me?

**I do have knowledge of the normal usage of IDisposable**. But I don't understand the following code. The instantiate of *new LogLog.LogReceivedAdapter(configurationMessages)* looks like have nothing to do with the code block within keyword using. How does statement *InternalConfigure(repository, configFile)* eventually update variable *configurationMessages*?

BTW, the code piece was grabbed from log4net XmlConfigurator.cs#508

```
static public ICollection Configure(ILoggerRepository repository, FileInfo configFile)
{
    ArrayList configurationMessages = new ArrayList();

    using (new LogLog.LogReceivedAdapter(configurationMessages))
    {
        InternalConfigure(repository, configFile);
    }

    repository.ConfigurationMessages = configurationMessages;

    return configurationMessages;
}
```

Comment: what's in the LogReceivedAdapter C'tor? and what is the implemntation of InternalConfigure()?

Comment: Weird code, even if it works you should refactor it if possible.

Comment: The instance of LogReceivedAdapter subscribes to a static event called LogReceive. This means any Log messages (error, info etc.) that occurs inside of the using statement, will be outputted to the configurationMessages variable. As soon as the closing brace of the using statement is reached it will unsubscribe the instance from the LogReceive event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know that exact code, but it **may** look like the following:

- LogLog registers `configurationMessages` in some static class (let's call it `Log`) upon construction;
- InternalConfigure uses that static class (and in effect configurationMessages are filled up)
- The Dispose() method of LogLog class removes the adapter from the `Log` class.

The part you presented requires heavy guessing, but I believe, that this is the case.

Comment: Yes, Spook, you are totally right. As migajek pasted what exactly the constructor of did, I finally got what it stands for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the constructor of `LogReceivedAdapter` is an answer.

```
public LogReceivedAdapter(IList items)
{
    this.items = items;

    handler = new LogReceivedEventHandler(LogLog_LogReceived);

    LogReceived += handler;
}
```

As you can see it does some magic behind, thus - even though there's no direct reference to newly created instance in your code - it might have some sense :)

Comment: I finally got it that LogReceived is a static event which is defined in its parent class Log. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

C# treats classes that implement IDisposable in one specific way: it calls Dispose() at the moment when the code reaches the closing bracket of the "using" block where the object was created. 
Look at Dispose() method of the LogLog.LogReceivedAdapter. The code ensures, that this method is called.